# Why The CGContext draw nothing when I fill path color before stroke path color.

Tags: ios, cgcontext, cgpath

Code like this

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(100, 100), NO, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 5, 5);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 100);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillPath(context);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor grayColor].CGColor);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

when I remove the fill color the image is correct.
But I can't understand why I add fill color the image is nothing?

Comment: You haven't created a path so the fill probably fills the whole context. You need to create a closed oath to fill it.

Comment: 1、If I don't have a path, how can stroke path take effect. 2、If I put fillPath method after the stoke path then the image is correct. How to explain this?

Comment: 1. You don't have a closed path that you can fill. You just have a line that you can stroke. 2. Most likely stroking the line makes it a closed path that allows you to fill it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the how you draw on the context.

Please try the following:

```
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0, 100, 100);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    //Set background color
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context,rect);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor grayColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 5, 5);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 100);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Now

```
 _testImage.image = image;
```

You will get the result. Please let me know your feedback.

Comment: It work. But you miss one line `CGContextFillPath(context);` If you add this line before`CGContextStrokePath(context)` ,the image is still empty... I feel confused. how the fillPath can effect the stroke path and how the fill and stroke sequence can affect the result.

Comment: Can you try with CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke) instead of CGContextStrokePath(context) at the same position. I think will work ..